# Is there a function to carry out unpaired Wilcoxon test for two samples in a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, pairwise.wilcox.test

I am trying to do an unpaired wilcoxon (Mann Whitney test) with a df containing gene expression values for two samples

```
  SampleA SampleA SampleA SampleB SampleB
```

gene1
gene2
gene3
..
..'

I have grouped the two sample types into SampleA and SampleB and using the following code to do a Wilcoxon test:

wilcox.test(df$tissueA, df$tissueB, paired=FALSE)

> Error in wilcox.test.default(df$tissueA, df$tissueB, paired = FALSE) :
> 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931518/apply-statistical-test-to-many-variables-improve-speed

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The first argument is `x=` and you provided `df$tissueA`. The error message says that `df$tissueA` is not a numeric variable. Is it? Since you did not provide a reproducible example, we cannot possibly know.